# React: How to save jsx to state then show jsx in dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to set the value of the variable `showMe` to some jsx and then save that in state.

```
 const showMe = `<span><div>${content.data[i].type}</div><div>${'EOS'+ content.data[i].quantity}</div><div>${'$ ' + content.data[i].price}</div><div>${'$ ' +Number(content.data[i].price*content.data[i].quantity).toLocaleString('en')}</div></span>`
setState({...state, showMe});
```

but then when I try to put the jsx into the dom i get it as a string that shows the html tags instead of interpreting them

```
{state.showMe}
```

I guess im saving the html as a string and not jsx? If so how to save jsx instead of the string?

I also tried

```
sellArray += <span><div>{content.data[i].type}</div><div>{'EOS ' + content.data[i].quantity}</div><div>{'$ ' + content.data[i].price}</div><div>{'$ ' +Number(content.data[i].price*content.data[i].quantity).toLocaleString('en')}</div></span>;
```

But the html just shows `[object Object]`

If i have the values as objects in an array I can map over it and it works just fine, but i dont want to have to do that.

```
const showMeArray = content.data.map((item: any) => <span><div>{item.type}</div><div>{'EOS ' + item.quantity}</div><div>{'$ ' + item.price}</div><div>{'$ ' +Number(item.price*item.quantity).toLocaleString('en')}</div></span>);
```

I dont understand why this works

Comment: Why would you not write showme as functional component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use babel to transform it

npm install --save babel-core

Then in your code

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
var Component = eval(babel.transform('<div><MyComponent /></div>').code);
```

Or you can use [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

class HtmlComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const html = '<div>Example HTML string</div>';
    return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(html) }</div>;
  }
}
```

But this is generally bad practise when transform string to execuatable code

Answer (score 0):

You can display `showMe` state variable in `dom` by the use of [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: state.showMe }}></div>
```

**Here is the working demo for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-i9ha5h**